# Xcode REST with RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, rest, restkit

I am trying to simulate the following request using RestKit:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-User: here@there.com" -H "X-Password: imapass" -D - -k https://api.application.com/v2/auth
```

I am looking for a little guidance as I am a relative noob to RestKit and the examples aren't helping.

For initialization I have:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager=[RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"https://api.application.com/v2"];
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

But I don't think I want to post an object so I'm guessing this is the wrong start...

I also tried the following:
    RKParams *params = [RKParams params];

```
// Attach the Image from Image View
NSData* user = [@"here@there.com" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* pass = [@"imapass"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[params setData:user forParam:@"X-User"];
[params setData:pass forParam:@"X-Password"];

// Send it for processing!
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.application.com/v2"];

RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:url];
[RKClient setSharedClient:client];

[client post:@"/auth" params:params delegate:self];
```

..but I am getting 404's.

I'm not looking for anybody to give me the answer but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
So I've managed to get the GET through by using:

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.application.com/v2"];

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:url];
[RKClient setSharedClient:client];
[client setValue:@"here@there.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-User"];
[client setValue:@"imapass" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Password"];

[client get:@"/auth" delegate:self];
```

...now its just a matter of getting the response token as JSON.

Baby steps..

Comment: Unless the server application is returning `404` instead of the standard `401` or `403` HTTP status codes for authorization failure, then the web server is not recognizing the value in `[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]` as a valid location. It would be helpful if there is a way you can intercept the curl request and the request generated from RestKit for comparison to see what HTTP headers are being created.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking the same thing so will have to look for sniffers I guess.